# Alternative to READ_PHONE_STATE permission for getting notified of call

Tags: android

I'm currently using the READ_PHONE_STATE permission in Android to pause my media player when there's a call, and to resume playback when the call is over. The permission seems to scare a lot of people, so I was wondering if there was an alternative to catching the starting and stopping of a phone call without it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think the [audio focus support](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html) is supposed to handle this, though I have not experimented with that portion of the SDK.

Comment: This worked! If you add it as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to adjust your audio output in response to something else wanting to perform audio output (e.g., an incoming phone call), look into Android's [audio focus support](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html).
`READ_PHONE_STATE`, as noted, is a bit of a scary permission. Moreover, it only deals with phone calls, and not other things that might need the same capability (e.g., VOIP calls, as AFAIK those don't tie into `READ_PHONE_STATE`-enabled stuff).

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, audio focus is not a substitute for READ_PHONE_STATE. My app has to use both. The standard phone app on my Galaxy S3 I9300/ Android 4.3 doesn't seem to request the audio focus at all. The TelephonyManager class gives you a way to detect the end of the phone call (by sending the CALL_STATE_IDLE state update). The AudioManager doesn't seem to do anything similar, so even if audio focus could be used, it would not be as useful. And, from what I see in the documentation, there doesn't seem to be a narrower permission than READ_PHONE_STATE that would allow the app to read the phone state but not the call information. If I'm wrong about any of this, please correct me.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, audio focus is not a substitute for READ_PHONE_STATE. My app has to use both. The standard phone app on my Galaxy S3 I9300/ Android 4.3 doesn't seem to request the audio focus at all. The TelephonyManager class gives you a way to detect the end of the phone call (by sending the CALL_STATE_IDLE state update). The AudioManager doesn't seem to do anything similar, so even if audio focus could be used, it would not be as useful. And, from what I see in the documentation, there doesn't seem to be a narrower permission than READ_PHONE_STATE that would allow the app to read the phone state but not the call information. If I'm wrong about any of this, please correct me.